# Access a docker images localhost from local machine

Tags: docker, jupyter, mesa

So I am trying to build an agent-based model service in docker which would serve up an agent-based model using Mesa. I have got the image to route to the jupyter notebook, it runs, but when it serves up the server on port 5000 I can't access through localhost. I am not sure where exactly it is serving it and how I may access it.

[image: server access]

The code can be found here:

https://github.com/PhilipDW183/airplane_abm

The notebook can be accessed at localhost:8888, but I am not sure where the mesa server is being served up is and how to access.

Any advice would be appreciated.

The hope is to eventually build this into a Flask app.

Comment: You can check IP for server by `docker inspect` command.

Comment: Its hosted on my machine and using docker inspect and using the IP I still can't access the interface presented here